# nginx map to different locations inside a location

Tags: nginx

Environment:

- webdav server running on localhost:10001
- nginx server running on port 80

Goal:

- nginx needs to have a single external /webdav location
- GET requests need to be served by the nginx autoindex
- All other request methods need to be proxied to the webdav server at localhost:10001
- GET and PROPFIND request methods need to be unauthenticaled (basic auth) while all other request methods need to be authenticated

Here is an example of what I tried, that I think conveys my intention but is not valid (map directive not allowed here).

```
    map webdav_location $request_method {
      GET @webdav-get;
      PROPFIND @webdav-list;
      default @webdav-auth;
    }

    location @webdav-get {
      autoindex on;
      alias /mnt/storage/;
    }

    location @webdav-list {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:10001;
    }

    location @webdav-auth {
      include conf.d/auth.conf;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:10001;
    }

    location /webdav {
      $webdav_location;
    }
```

I've also made some attempts using if statements, but I read that one should avoid using if statements inside nginx conf. Hence I tried something using a map, as I think my intention is to map based on the request_method but perhaps other methods are better to achieve my goal?

Thank you for reading

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.